# Grails 3.1.6 DataSource plugin unable to be configured to handle PKI for securing data communication

Tags: grails, ssl

I have created a simple index.gsp, using Grails 3.1.6, whose content is an embedded Java code connecting to Oracle 12c via SSL/TLS.
The URL is a string invoking the TCPS protocol, uses the thin JDBC driver for connecting to Oracle 12c. The password, username, trust store path/type/password, key store path/type/password, cipher suites are specified by the Java utility properties.
Once a secured connection is established the Grails GSP queries the current date and time of the database server. **This works.**

Below is my GSP's content.

```
<%@ page import = "java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import = "java.util.Properties" %>
<%
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=jreportdbsvr)" +
        "(PORT=1525))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=sid.mydomain)))";
Driver driver = new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", "username");
props.setProperty("password", "userpassword");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","H:/minh_workspace/pki/my-grails-app.jks");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","JKS");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","my-grails-password");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","H:/minh_workspace/pki/my-grails-app.jks");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","JKS");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","my-grails-password");
props.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites", "SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA");
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement stmt = null;
Connection conn = driver.connect(url, props);
stmt = conn.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select sysdate from dual");
while (rs.next()) {
%>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><h3><"Current date and time from Oracle 12c : "></h3></td>
    <td><h3><%=rs.getString(1)%></h3></td>
</tr>
<%
    }
rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
%>
```

I have tried ***in vain*** to configure Grails application.yml to implement the above setup, especially in the environments: development: datasource: ....
**scenario 1:**

```
environments:
development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=jreportdbsvr)(PORT=1525))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=sid.mydomain)))
        properties:
        .... no specification of trust / key stores, ciphersuite ....
```

**error message:**

"java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

**comment:**
Obviously it is looking for valid certification that I intentionally omitted in this scenario.

**scenario 2:**

```
environments:
development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=jreportdbsvr)(PORT=1525))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=sid.mydomain)))
        properties:
          javax.net.ssl.trustStore:  /local/tomcat/certificates/my-grails-app.jks
          javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType: JKS
          javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword: my-grails-password
          javax.net.ssl.keyStore: /local/tomcat/certificates/my-grails-app.jks
          javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType: JKS
          javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword: my-grails-password
          javax.net.ssl.ssl_cipher_suites: (SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
```

**error message:**
"........Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'javax' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]:
Bean property 'javax' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?..."

**comment:**
Grails does not recognize these properties ... javax.net.ssl.trustStore

**scenario 3:**

```
            development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=jreportdbsvr)(PORT=1525))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=sid.mydomain)))
        properties:
           ......
            ssl:
              trust-store: H:/minh_workspace/pki/my-grails-app.jks
              trust-store-type: JKS
              trust-store-password: my-grails-password
              key-store: H:/minh_workspace/pki/my-grails-app.jks
              key-store-type: JKS
              key-store-password: my-grails-password
              cipher-suites: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

**error message:**
"Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'ssl' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]:
Bean property 'ssl' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Did you mean 'url'? "

**comment:**     Grails does recognize the way I specified those properties.

**My question is how would I specify the properties I had in the index.gsp into either the application.yml or the configuration.groovy?**

Thanks in advance,

Minh

HPCMPO

Lorton, Virginia

Comment: Can you share the entire stack trace?

Comment: Colin, here it is.

Comment: The trace is too long for this editor so I emailed it.

Comment: Finally, yesterday (2016.05.26) our team figured it out to make it work. I will share with stackoverflow what we did next week after my long weekend. Cheers.

Comment: 2016.06.15 update. It worked when deployed in the DEV environment but failed in the PRODUCTION one. When the war file was created and deployed in a stand-alone TOMCAT it failed. Go to this link for more information  https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9991